# How to connect absolute encoder on the rotating shaft. Please see the three options?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, robotics, encoder

[image]

[image]

Hi,
Here I have added 2 options for connecting encoder on shaft.
Motor, gearhead and shaft is connected using coupling. But where will be best place for encoder (To avoid backlash from coupling and gearhead).
whether through hollow encoder is available? (see option 1).
I dont know which one will be best for this kind of system. 
Which one is widely using arrangements?

**Options 3** is Encoder will be placed before the motor.

Comment: As long as the shaft is rigid enough, does it really matter?

Comment: None of these account for wear, flex or backlash in the leadscrew nut assembly.

Comment: Does option 2 not specifically address this by sensing the shaft independent of the motor and gearbox?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing for angular accuracy is that the encoder is in rigid contact with the load you are driving.

From your drawings, it appears that the load is a leadscrew shaft.

Either option that puts the encoder on the shaft will be OK, for accuracy.

There will be other mechanical constraints. The difference between your options 1 and 2 is that the encoder can physically support the end of the shaft. This may be good or bad, depending on how the encoder is rated, whether side-loads will decrease its accuracy, whether you want the shaft supported at both ends or free at the far end, and your assembly tolerances. You will need the spec of your components, and the spec of what you are trying to achieve, to know which.